# For vs To. What is the differences?

Tags: grammar, difference

*Are there any differences between useing **For** or **To** in some situations like these?*

> `For improving` your writing, you have to read book more.
>
> `To improve` your writing, you have to read book more.

> I killed that person `to protect` you.
>
> I killed that person `for protecting` you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, no. It's just a stylistic choice. 'Improving' is a good choice in your first example because the  nicely conveys *ongoing improvement*.

In your second example though, it's a complete disaster. You've changed the meaning entirely. "*I killed that person for protecting you*" sounds like the first person killed someone *for the reason that* they protected the second person.